# update label after every X seconds in cooca mac application

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, loops

I am having a mac app in which I want to update my label after some seconds.

I have used the following code with NSTimer.

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0/30 target:self selector:@selector(count:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

float k = 0.0;

```
    if (k >= 958.36)
    {
        [timer invalidate];
        return;
    }
     NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", k];
     NSLog(@"%@",string);
    [lbl setStringValue:string];

    k++;
```

When I am using this code the value increases like below.

```
1.00
2.00
3.00
4.00
5.00
```

It only updates the integer values but not the decimal numbers. It should work like 1.10,1.11,1.12...

I know there are lots of questions on this and solutions but didn't work for me.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `k++` is the issue as that is incrementing `k` by `1.0`.

Increment using a different value, for example:

```
k += 0.1f;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I passed a time 1.0/1.000 but numbers loop slightly slow. How can I make it more faster?

Comment: @Manthan That is waaay too short of a timeout to work correctly.  I would say don't go lower than 1/10 second as the user won't see anything update faster than this anyway.  So go slower but update the value with more (i.e. `k += 0.1` as in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You're printing `k`, which you are increasing by 1 every time the timer fires. If you want to print 1.10,1.11,1.12 et.c. you need to use:

```
NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1.%2f", k+10];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if (k >= 958.36)
{
    [timer invalidate];
    return;
}
 NSString* string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", k];
 NSLog(@"%@",string);
[lbl setStringValue:string];

k += 0.01f;
```

Comment: Errr, isn't this a copy of my answer, just with additional, unnecessary code?

Comment: Sir, i think there is diff. between k += 0.1f; and k += 0.01f;

Comment: Your code print 1.10,1.20,1.30 and other one print 1.10,1.11,1.12, and so on

Comment: The actual value isn't really important; the use of `k++` was the root cause of the issue.  I'm sure manthan will work out the correct value for himself.

Comment: @Droppy: Yes true... That is why I accepted your answer.